# Counting the most tagged tag with MySQL

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysql, tags

My problem is that I'm trying to count which tag has been used most in a table of user-submitted code. But the problem is with the database structure.

The current query I'm using is this:

```
SELECT tag1, COUNT(tag1) AS counttag 
FROM code 
GROUP BY tag1 
ORDER BY counttag DESC LIMIT 1
```

This is fine, except, it only counts the most often occurence of tag1 - and my database has 5 tags per post - so there's columns tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4, tag5. How do I get the highest occurring tag value from all 5 columns in one query?

Jack

Comment: Thanks for the edit Davek! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should make 2-3 tables. I usually make 3:

### code

- id
- code

### code_tags:

- code_id
- tag_id

### tags:

- id
- name

To make a query which shows the amount of tags used:

```
   SELECT t.*, COUNT(tag_id) as code_count 
     FROM code_tags ct 
LEFT JOIN tags t ON ct.tag_id = t.id 
 GROUP BY tag_id 
 ORDER BY code_count DESC 
    LIMIT 1
```

Comment: +1: For correct modeling and query.  Formatting your answer so it's easier to read will pay dividends - see the markdown reference: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: and adding `count` field to `tags` table for storing the precalculated value of each tag count is acceptable too.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select tag, Count(tag) AS counttag 
From (
    Select tag1 As tag
    From code
    Union All
    Select tag2 As tag
    From code
    Union All
    Select tag3 As tag
    From code
    ...
) t
Group BY tag
Order BY counttag Desc Limit 1
```

---

The better approach would be to normalize your tables (also see [mark_dj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571888/counting-the-most-tagged-tag-with-mysql/2571904#2571904)):

Table **code_tag** (contains all tags of a code):

```
Code_id
Tag
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're correct that your database structure is the problem.

You *could* create an SQL query, which contains subqueries, each one passing over the same table and pulling out information about each tag field. However, I'd suggest two alternatives:

1. Just make 5 different queries. Unless you *specifically* need this information in one SQL query (which seems unlikely), it's going to be much simpler to just make 5 requests to the DB and then organise the information programatically
2. Fix your DB structure to use join tables. I'd hazard a guess that this is just the first of any number of problems that you're going to come across because of this DB structure.

By join tables, you're looking at 2 extra tables:

```
CREATE TABLE code_tags {
  code_id INT,
  tag_id INT
}

CREATE TABLE tags {
  id INT,
  other fields
}
```

Instead of having `tagX` fields in your `code` tables, you use the join table to add tags